# subset matrix data based on the different names in a column

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 1000 rows and 9 columns. In the second column, I have repeated names and I want to subset my matrix based on the "first" ten "different" names in this column. How can I write it?

```
#example:
 sig<-c(6,7,12,13,16,18,16,11,11,12,12,10,12,13,15,16,16,18,16,17,15,11,12,12)  
name<-c(a,a,a,a,b,b,g,g,j,j,k,k,f,t,t,t,r,w,s,s,h,h,o,o)
```

The second column is "name" and I want to subset (a,a,a,a,b,b,g,g,j,j,k,k,f,t,t,t,r,w,s,s). They are first ten different names.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I tried many thing but they are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
# generate some data
set.seed(1)
m1 <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=sample(letters, 20, replace=T),
                           b=rnorm(20)))

head(m1)
     a   b            
[1,] "g" " 1.51178117"
[2,] "j" " 0.38984324"
[3,] "o" "-0.62124058"
[4,] "x" "-2.21469989"
[5,] "f" " 1.12493092"
[6,] "x" "-0.04493361"
```

So the first three unique "names" in column `a` are `g, j, o`. 
Now you can subset the matrix as follows:

```
m1[m1[, 1] %in% unique(m1[, 1])[1:3], ]


     a   b            
[1,] "g" " 1.51178117"
[2,] "j" " 0.38984324"
[3,] "o" "-0.62124058"
[4,] "j" "-1.98935170"
[5,] "j" "-0.47815006"
```

Comment: but I don't want unique names. Please see my example.

Comment: @Betty `unique` extracts the unique values out of a vector (in this case). In my example I then take the first three of those and subset on that. So it subsets on the "first" three "different" names. Change the 3 to 10 and, in my eyes, it is as your example.

Comment: yes, sorry, ten was in my mind. You are right.